# Protractor test- trying to print the text value of multiple webelements by iterating them in a for loop

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am new to protractor tests and I have been trying to print text value out of multiple webelements to the console. I would like to use the "element.all" notation to store the values in a variable and then iterate through the array and print the text in them one by one. I have tried many different ways and read about the promises and tried to handle them through .filter, .get , .each functions but nothing gets printed in the console

Here is the sample code that I tried

```
    // spec.js
describe('Protractor Demo App', function() {
    var firstNumber = element(by.model('first'));
    var secondNumber = element(by.model('second'));
    var goButton = element(by.id('gobutton'));
    var latestResult = element(by.binding('latest'));
    var history = element.all(by.repeater('result in memory'))

    function add (a, b){
        firstNumber.sendKeys(a);
        secondNumber.sendKeys(b);
        goButton.click();
    }

    beforeEach(function() {
        browser.get('http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/');
    });

    it('should have a title', function() {
        expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('Super Calculator');
    });

    it('should have a history', function() {
        add(1, 2);
        add(3,4);

        expect(history.count()).toEqual(2);

        add(5,6);

        expect(history.count()).toEqual(3); // This is correct!
    });

    it('should have a history2', function() {
        add(1,2);
        add(3,4);
        for (var i =0; i < history.lenght; i++){
            history.get[i].getText().then(function (text){
                console.log(text);
            });
        }

    });


});
```

The second 'it" block is where I am trying this. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
// Option 1
function printHistory1() {
    history.each(function(item){
        item.getText().then(function(txt, index){
            console.log('Add result['+(index+1)+'] = ' + txt);
        })
    });
}
// Option 2
function printHistory2() {
    history.getText().then(function(results){
        results.forEach(function(txt, index){
            console.log('Add result['+(index+1)+'] = ' + txt);
        });
    })
}

it('should have a history', function() {
        add(1, 2);
        add(3,4);

        printHistory1();
        expect(history.count()).toEqual(2);

        add(5,6);

        printHistory2();
        expect(history.count()).toEqual(3); // This is correct!
});
```

There are some issue in the  `Third` it block

```
it('should have a history2', function() {
    add(1,2);
    add(3,4);


    for (var i =0; i < history.length; i++) { 
        history.get[i].getText().then(function (text){
            console.log(text);
        });
    }

    // element.all() not has `length` property, you should use `count()` which also return a Pormise.
    // the correct way to use `count()` to archive same purpose

    history.count().then(function(count){
        for (var i =0; i < count; i++) {
            (function(index){
                history.get[i].getText().then(function (text){
                    console.log(text);
                });
            }) // ()  returns a function, and () at here make javascript closure
            (i); // (i) it's to call function with argument: i
        }
    });

});
```